# Media9 in beamer

Tags: beamer, media9

When I run below code in my Linux system, there are some errors which I cannot understand where they come from.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{embed a movie}
\begin{center}
\includemedia[
    width=0.4\linewidth,height=0.3\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,
    addresource=lowrey.flv,
    flashvars={
       source=lowrey.flv}
]{\includegraphics[height=0.3\linewidth]{}{VPlayer9.swf}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And here are the errors:

```
File ended while scanning use of \frame.

No file document.nav.
```

Can anyone help me to solve the errors? They made me frustrated.

Comment: There is a opening brace before \includegraphics which isn't closed anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `{\includegraphics[height=0.3\linewidth]{}{VPlayer9.swf}` cant be wright. Should it be `{\includegraphics[height=0.3\linewidth]{VPlayer9.pdf}}`? `\includegraphics` does not handle `.swf`, it handles images ...

Comment: Well, such video tutorials often contain errors. Better follow the documentation of used packages ...  You can try `{\includegraphics[height=0.3\linewidth]{example-image}}{VPlayer9.swf}}`

Answer (score 3):

I do not have your used file `lowrey.flv` but with using the standard file `cube.mp4` from `media9` package I can compile this code without errors:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{embed a movie}
\begin{center}
\includemedia[%
    width=0.4\linewidth,height=0.3\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,
    addresource=cube.mp4,
    flashvars={source=cube.mp4}
]{\includegraphics[height=0.3\linewidth]{cubeposter.png}}{VPlayer9.swf}% <=============
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Please see that I used the corrected line:

```
{\includegraphics[height=0.3\linewidth]{cubeposter.png}}{VPlayer9.swf}
```

Comment: your code can be compiled in my laptop, but doesn't show the movie!

Comment: it shows the poster and there is a part in which it is written: embed a movie

Comment: I am using Linux